# On Fancytree jquery plugin what is the event that occur when no data presented?

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I using the fancytree plugin.

sometimes i get empty data from the server(because this the result of the user input). but i want to know that ther is no data.

what is the event when there is no data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `loadChildren` event which fires when the initial nodes are loaded (and after lazy nodes are expanded and loaded).
`data.node.children` contains the result then.
`loadError` is another event you may want to know of:

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  loadChildren: function(event, data) {
    console.log(event.type, data.node.children.length);
  },
  loadError: function(event, data) {
    console.log(event.type, data);
  },
```